# implode("\0", $hoge);

Tags: php

下記コードはどういう意味でしょうか？

```
  implode("\0", $hoge);
```

---

**"\0"で連結？**
・"\0"はヌル文字？
・文字列の終端？

**"\0"で連結すると、どんな良いことがあるのでしょうか？**
・連結する際、間にスペースがあったら削除するとか、そういうことでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\0`は文字列の終端を表す文字として用いられます。
`\0`自体は**NULL文字**と言う認識で大丈夫です。

PHPには文字列と言う概念がありますが文字列の概念が無い言語もあります。
そういう言語のために"ここが文字列の終端ですよ"と表すための文字ですね
他の言語でも読み込むリソースなんですかね？

配列を行として扱った1つの文字列にする。
が上記コードだと思います。

Answer (score 0):

試してみましたがヌル文字で連結されるようです。

間のスペースを削除するということはなかったです。

意図はよくはわからないので推測ですが、

連結した後また分解する必要があって、
その時のために通常の文字を使いたくない（セパレータとして例えば`,`のような文字を選ぶと文字列の内容自体にそのような文字が含まれる可能性があって元通りに分解できなくなるとか）ということで
ヌル文字を使用しているのかもしれません。